# How to print balance in a banking program (Java)

Tags: java

I have created a Java program for banking, which allows the user to deposit funds, withdraw funds, and check their balance.

However, I would like to be able to print the `convToString` data (`name`, `accNo`, `balance`) whenever the `getBalance()` command is called. This would be much more effective than having to type `System.out.println(JohnSmith.convToString()+"\n")` each time I want to print the account information.

Any advice on how best to clean my code up and make this happen?

My full source code follows...

```
package week1src;

public class BankAccount {
    
    private String name;
    private int accNo;  
    private double balance;
    
    
    // Constructor to initialise all 3 instance variables
    public BankAccount(String n, int a, double amount)
    {   
        name = n;
        accNo = a;
        balance = amount;
    }
    
    // Constructor to set default opening account balance to zero
    public BankAccount(String n, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        accNo = a;
        balance = 0.00;
    }
    
    
    /* --------------------
       Return a String containing all the information of the account based on account name input
       --------------------*/
    public String convToString(  ) 
    {
        return("Account name: " + this.name + ", Account number: " + this.accNo + ", Available balance: " + "£" + this.balance);
    }
    
    
    /* --------------------
       Method to deposit funds by adding "amount" to balance 
       --------------------*/
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        if (amount <= 0) { 
            // returns an error message is value entered is negative
            System.err.println("Cannot deposit negative amounts. Please enter a different amount.");
        }
        else {
            this.balance += amount;
            System.out.format("£%.2f has been deposited\n", amount);
        }
    }
    
        
    /* --------------------
       Method to withdraw funds by subtracting "amount" from balance 
       --------------------*/
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        if (this.balance >= amount) { 
            this.balance -= amount;
            System.out.format("£%.2f has been withdrawn\n", amount);
        }
        else { // returns an error message if withdrawal with put account balance below 0
            System.err.println("Transaction cancelled due to insufficient funds. Check balance or deposit funds.");
        }
    }
    
    
    /* --------------------
       Method used to display account balance 
       --------------------*/
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
        // i want to print the convToString info whenever getBalance() is called.
    }
}
```

---

```
package week1src;

public class BankMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        BankAccount JohnSmith = new BankAccount("John Smith", 1, 00);   // create an account object (acc name, acc no, opening balance)
        //BankAccount DavidJones = new BankAccount("David Jones", 2, 1000);     // create an account object (acc name, acc no, opening balance)
                
        System.out.println(JohnSmith.convToString()+"\n"); // will display acc name, acc number, and current balance (£0)
        JohnSmith.deposit(100); // deposit £100             
        JohnSmith.deposit(-50); // will return error due to negative value
        JohnSmith.deposit(10);  // deposit £10
        JohnSmith.withdraw(25); // withdraw £25
        JohnSmith.withdraw(90); // will return error as balance will go <0
        System.out.println(JohnSmith.getBalance()); // display balance
        JohnSmith.withdraw(70); // withdraw £70     
        System.out.println(JohnSmith.convToString()+"\n"); // will display acc name, acc number, and current balance (£15.00)
        
                                
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a call to `System.out.println` in `getBalance` to output the value you want?  I guess it's not clear to me what you're asking.  You want to print the value without having to call `System.out.println` at all?

Comment: I tried that, but it says unreachable code. That's basically what I'm trying to do though instead of having to instantiate it each time in the BankMain class.

Comment: The code in the question shows no such attempt and produces no such error.  Perhaps in your attempt you put that line of code in the wrong place?  (Such as after the `return` statement?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved like this:

BankAccount.java:

```
public class BankAccount {

  private String name;
  private int accNo;
  private double balance;


  // Constructor to initialise all 3 instance variables
  public BankAccount(String n, int a, double amount) {
    name = n;
    accNo = a;
    balance = amount;
  }

  // Constructor to set default opening account balance to zero
  public BankAccount(String n, int a) {
    name = n;
    accNo = a;
    balance = 0.00;
  }


  /* --------------------
     Method to deposit funds by adding "amount" to balance
     --------------------*/
  public void deposit(double amount) {
    if (amount <= 0) {
      // returns an error message is value entered is negative
      System.err.println("Cannot deposit negative amounts. Please enter a different amount.");
    } else {
      this.balance += amount;
      System.out.format("£%.2f has been deposited\n", amount);
    }
  }


  /* --------------------
     Method to withdraw funds by subtracting "amount" from balance
     --------------------*/
  public void withdraw(double amount) {
    if (this.balance >= amount) {
      this.balance -= amount;
      System.out.format("£%.2f has been withdrawn\n", amount);
    } else { // returns an error message if withdrawal with put account balance below 0
      System.err.println(
          "Transaction cancelled due to insufficient funds. Check balance or deposit funds.");
    }
  }


  /* --------------------
     Method used to display account balance
     --------------------*/
  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
    // i want to print the convToString info whenever getBalance() is called.
  }

  public void printAccountInfo() {
    System.out.println(this);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Account name: " + this.name + ", Account number: " + this.accNo
        + ", Available balance: " + "£" + this.balance;
  }
}
```

BankMain.java:

```
package your.package.here;

public class BankMain{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BankAccount JohnSmith = new BankAccount("John Smith", 1,
        0);   // create an account object (acc name, acc no, opening balance)
    //BankAccount DavidJones = new BankAccount("David Jones", 2, 1000);     // create an account object (acc name, acc no, opening balance)

    JohnSmith.printAccountInfo();
    JohnSmith.deposit(100); // deposit £100
    JohnSmith.deposit(-50); // will return error due to negative value
    JohnSmith.deposit(10);  // deposit £10
    JohnSmith.withdraw(25); // withdraw £25
    JohnSmith.withdraw(90); // will return error as balance will go <0
    System.out.println(JohnSmith.getBalance()); // display balance
    JohnSmith.withdraw(70); // withdraw £70
    JohnSmith.printAccountInfo();
  }
}
```

It seems reasonable to create a separate reusable printing method, that will do all what you need. And instead of creating your `convToString` method, you can just override `toString` and then use it in a way that I've posted. This is built in java mechanism that do exactly what you need.

Tricky thing here is when you're calling `System.out.println(this);` default behavior is to call `toString` method on that object that you've passed to the `System.out.println` method.

And here is the magic happens, you just override `toString`, and then call `System.out.println` on your object instance. It will then take your instance and call your overrided `toString` on that.

Please, have a look.

Comment: I've updated answer a bit, please take a look.

Comment: Excellent/11  Thanks again. Now I just need to work out how to format it correctly to show the result as £15.00